# # Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

I'am new to Python and When I compile the Python code below, I get

## Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

plz help me to fix

### this is my script

```
from maya import cmds

sel = cmds.ls(sl=1)
controller = None
preParent = None
for i in sel:
    cmds.select(cl=1)
    if controller == None or cmds.objExists(controller) == False:
        controller1 = cmds.circle( nr=(1, 0, 0 ), name = i+"Ctrl")[0]
    else:
         controller1 = cmds.duplicate(controller, name = i + "Ctrl")[0]

     grp = cmds.group(em =1, name = i+"Grp")
     cmds.parent(controller1, grp)
     pc = cmds.parentConstraint(i, grp, mo=0)
     cmds.delete(pc)
     cmds.pointConstraint(controller1, i, mo=0)
     cmds.orientConstraint(controller1, i, mo=0)
     if preParent != None:
         cmds.parent(grp, preParent)
     preParent = controller1
```

Comment: The tab at the start! You need to remove it

Comment: [No tagline in questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), don't make text bold arbitrarily, and add full error message to the question, includes the line number.

Comment: And the code below the `else` block is indented by an extra space.

Comment: Also, this is a problem caused by a typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I ran your code through [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm-edu/download/#section=windows) format function.

```
from maya import cmds

sel = cmds.ls(sl=1)
controller = None
preParent = None
for i in sel:
    cmds.select(cl=1)
    if controller == None or cmds.objExists(controller) == False:
        controller1 = cmds.circle(nr=(1, 0, 0), name=i + "Ctrl")[0]
    else:
        controller1 = cmds.duplicate(controller, name=i + "Ctrl")[0]

    grp = cmds.group(em=1, name=i + "Grp")
    cmds.parent(controller1, grp)
    pc = cmds.parentConstraint(i, grp, mo=0)
    cmds.delete(pc)
    cmds.pointConstraint(controller1, i, mo=0)
    cmds.orientConstraint(controller1, i, mo=0)
    if preParent != None:
        cmds.parent(grp, preParent)
    preParent = controller1
```

Comment: Do you see that all the code after the `else` had an extra space before it ?

Comment: yes that seems to have fixed the problem. I haven't done any coding before so wound up with this error. Thanks for helping me out.